# Is there such a thing as a metric space of sets over an underlying metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

Typically we think of a metric as a notion of distance between elements of set subject to the following constraints...

$$
    d(x, y) ≥ 0,\quad d(x, x) = 0,\quad d(x, y) = d(y, x),\quad d(x, z) ≤ d(x, y) + d(y, z) 
$$

I want to know if there is an equivalent for distance between subsets of a known metric space? For example, if we partition integers between 1 and 20 into blocks of 5 and label these A, B, C and D, can we say that these labels are also metrics given a sensible method to compare them?
E.g. 
$$
    d(A,B) = \Big|\sum(1,2,3,4,5) - \sum(6,7,8,9,10)\Big| = 25,\\ 
    d(A,A) = \sum(1,2,3,4,5) - \sum(1,2,3,4,5) = 0, \mathrm{etc}.
$$

I'm sure there must be a solid definition of this somewhere with appropriate constraints on the sets. What I am particularly interested in is whether the concept of a metric distance is transitive from pairwise comparisons of elements to pairwise comparisons of subsets the metric space elements are taken from rather than an answer like "if you define a reasonable distance measure you can always call it a metric".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a metric set X, the [Hausdorff metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) is a metric on the set of non-empty compact subsets of X.

Comment: Fantastic :). Exactly what I needed.